# AT commands do not work on BLE HM 10 through Arduino

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, connectivity, hm-10

I've tried to send AT commands to my Ble 4.0 HM-10 module by connecting it to an Arduino Board and sending command through Arduino IDE's Serial Monitor but I don't get any response.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Also when I'm near the Bluetooth module my Android phone can connect and send data to the module. But when I'm close and there is a small obstacle between my phone and the module, the module doesn't receive the data but remains connected.

Can someone tell me the reason?

Thank You

Answer (score -1):

set your line ending to no line ending